# Issue with Supabase Flutter Integration: Unable to Update Row

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-flutter

I am currently working on a Flutter application that utilizes Supabase as its backend. I have encountered an issue where Supabase is not updating a specific row in my database.

Below is the relevant code snippet from my Flutter application:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class Debug extends StatelessWidget {
  const Debug({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          child: const Text("Debug"),
          onPressed: () {
            try {
              Supabase.instance.client
                  .from('transponder')
                  .update({'person': 3}).eq('id', 2);
            } catch (error) {
              print(error);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an overview of my database schema:

- `transponder(id, name, code, person)`
- `person(id, username, admin)`
- `checkin(id, created_at, person, transponder)`

I have ensured that there are constraints between the necessary objects, and I have disabled RLS (Row-Level Security) on all tables.

Despite these precautions, the row update operation does not seem to take effect. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how it can be resolved.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the calls.

```dart
await Supabase.instance.client
  .from('transponder')
  .update({'person': 3}).eq('id', 2);
```

Comment: Aaahh. I forgot about that. Thankyou!